# Netsh.exe run line

Tags: c#, netsh

Consider:

```
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo netshprocess = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
 netshprocess.FileName = "netsh.exe";
 string temp = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
 string user = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
 {
     user += temp[i];
     if (temp[i] == '\\')
     {
         user = "";
     }
  }
  netshprocess.Arguments = "";
  netshprocess.Arguments = "http add urlacl url=http://+:7015/MeasurementTransferWCF user=" + user;
  netshprocess.UseShellExecute = true;
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(netshprocess).WaitForExit();
```

I cannot seem to get it to run it through the code. When I open netsh.exe and manually type in the exact string that the code has for the argument, it works (tested and then deleted the add so I can can try and do it in code). I have tried in running as administrator mode as well, but it doesn't work. What am I missing to get it to run?

It *doesn’t* error. It just doesn't run the argument when *process.start* is called.

Comment: Remove the `catch (Exception) { }` and find out for yourself. You also may want to read the process's standard and error output.

Comment: Its not getting cought in the try catch and it doesn't crash if its not there its opening the netsh and closing just isn't running the arguement @codecaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
 System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo netshprocess = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
 netshprocess.FileName = "netsh.exe";

 string temp = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
 string user = "";

 for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
 {
     user += temp[i];
     if (temp[i] == '\\')
     {
         user = "";
     }
 }

 netshprocess.Verb = "runas";
 netshprocess.Arguments = "";
 netshprocess.Arguments = "http add urlacl url=http://+:7015/MeasurementTransferWCF user=" + user;
 netshprocess.UseShellExecute = true;

 try
 {
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(netshprocess).WaitForExit();
 }
 catch (Exception)
 { }
```

With the verb run as when the user clicks "yes", it will be added. But if they click "no", you now need to catch the exception as it will git failed to run error.

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly but is there anyway to only run the verb line if the current program is running as admin???

Comment: *"it will git failed to run error"* is incomprehensible. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28830643/edit) it?